# How to obtain the current path to my google colab file?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I work with google colab on my google drive. When I do

```
import os 
cwd= os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
```

it return

> /content

. How to obtain the path to my google colab file like

> /content/drive/path_to_my_current_google_colab_file

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.colab \
import drive
import os, glob

my_name = 'my.ipynb'

drive.mount(os.getcwd() + '/drive')
my_path = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '/**/' +
my_name, recursive = True)

# some 'list comprehension'.
my_path = [my_i
for my_i in my_path if len(my_i) in [max([len(my_i)
for my_i in my_path])]
][0]; print(my_path)
```